# Writing excel files with Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, xlsxwriter

What I expect this code to do:

1. Find elements on a web page
2. Iterate through the web elements and convert them into text format
3. Format cell value so that "B" cell number increases by 1 at each iteration.
4. **Write each of the web elements the first for loop iterated through into each of the generated B cells**
5. Save the excel file

What the code currently does:

1. Finds elements on a web page
2. Iterates through these web elements and converts them into text format
3. Formats cell value so that "B" cell number increases by 1 at each iteration.
4. **Writes the last web element the first for loop iterated through into each of the generated B cells.**
5. Saves the excel file

So instead of having this in the excel spreadsheet:

Apple

Apple

Apple

Apple

I expect it to give this output in the spreadsheet:

Apple

Banana

Orange

Kiwi

```
 product_name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('s-item__title')  # finds names of each of the listings on each of the pages
    for t in product_name:
        for h in range(0, 100):#Cell position generator
            a = h + 1
            worksheet.write('B{}'.format(a), t.text)
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
product_name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('s-item__title')  
for t, h in zip(product_name, range(0, len(product_name))):
    a = h + 1
    worksheet.write('B{}'.format(a), t.text)
workbook.close()
```